# How to speed up LINQ inserts with SQL CE?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, optimization, sql-server-ce

**History**

I have a list of "records" (3,500) which I save to XML and compress on exit of the program. Since:

- the number of the records increases
- only around 50 records need to be updated on exit
- saving takes about 3 seconds

I needed another solution -- embedded database. I chose SQL CE because it works with VS without any problems and the license is OK for me (I compared it to **Firebird**, **SQLite**, **EffiProz**, **db4o** and **BerkeleyDB**).

**The data**

The record structure: 11 fields, 2 of them make primary key (nvarchar + byte). Other records are bytes, datatimes, double and ints.

I don't use any relations, joins, indices (except for primary key), triggers, views, and so on. It is flat Dictionary actually -- pairs of Key+Value. I modify some of them, and then I have to update them in database. From time to time I add some new "records" and I need to store (insert) them. That's all.

**LINQ approach**

I have blank database (file), so I make 3500 inserts in a loop (one by one). I don't even check if the record already exists because db is blank.

Execution time? 4 minutes, 52 seconds. I fainted (mind you: XML + compress = 3 seconds).

**SQL CE raw approach**

I googled a bit, and despite such claims as here:
[LINQ to SQL (CE) speed versus SqlCe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111125/linq-to-sql-ce-speed-versus-sqlce)
stating it is SQL CE itself fault I gave it a try.

The same loop but this time inserts are made with SqlCeResultSet (DirectTable mode, see: [Bulk Insert In SQL Server CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539277/bulk-insert-in-sqlce)) and SqlCeUpdatableRecord.

The outcome? Do you sit comfortably? Well... 0.3 second (yes, fraction of the second!).

**The problem**

LINQ is **very** readable, and raw operations are quite contrary. I could write a mapper which translates all column indexes to meaningful names, but it seems like reinventing the wheel -- after all it is already done in... LINQ.

So maybe it is a way to tell LINQ to speed things up? **QUESTION** -- how to do it?

**The code**

**LINQ**

```
foreach (var entry in dict.Entries.Where(it => it.AlteredByLearning))
{
    PrimLibrary.Database.Progress record = null;

        record = new PrimLibrary.Database.Progress();
        record.Text = entry.Text;
        record.Direction = (byte)entry.dir;
        db.Progress.InsertOnSubmit(record);

    record.Status = (byte)entry.LastLearningInfo.status.Value;
    // ... and so on

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**Raw operations**

SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "Progress";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect;
SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable);

```
foreach (var entry in dict.Entries.Where(it => it.AlteredByLearning))
{
    SqlCeUpdatableRecord record = null;

    record = rs.CreateRecord();

    int col = 0;
    record.SetString(col++, entry.Text);
    record.SetByte(col++,(byte)entry.dir);
    record.SetByte(col++,(byte)entry.LastLearningInfo.status.Value);
    // ... and so on

    rs.Insert(record);
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code examples?

Comment: @Kevin Pullin, sure, I added the essential parts to get understanding how I do inserts in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)?

Comment: @svick, could you please explain what serializing objects has to do with LINQ in this case?

Comment: @macias, nothing, but you said that saving into XML was too slow. Instead of using ordinary SQL database, using `BinaryFormatter` would be easier and could be fast enough. It seems you don't most features of actual database, so something lighter might be better (and possibly even faster).

Comment: @svick, you are right but two crucial points are not solved by serializing -- you are dumping each time 3500 records, despite 50 were changed. Number of the records increases so it will be slower in time, and see problem one -- 50 records should be saved. So your solution is actually very temporary workaround, but sooner or later I would have to use embedded database with ability to save only few selected records (and without reinventing the wheel).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Do more work per transaction.**

Commits are generally *very expensive operations* for a typical relational database as the database must wait for disk flushes to ensure data is not lost ([ACID guarantees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and all that). Conventional HDD disk IO without specialty controllers is *very slow* in this sort of operation: the data *must* be flushed to the physical disk -- *perhaps only 30-60 commits can occur a second with an IO sync between!*

See the SQLite FAQ: [INSERT is really slow - I can only do few dozen INSERTs per second](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). Ignoring the different database engine, this is the exact same issue.

Normally, **LINQ2SQL creates a new implicit transaction** inside `SubmitChanges`. To avoid this implicit transaction/commit (*commits are expensive operations*) either:

1. Call `SubmitChanges` less (say, once *outside* the loop) or;
2. Setup an explicit transaction scope (see [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)).

One example of using a larger transaction context is:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope()) {
  // LINQ2SQL will automatically enlist in the transaction scope.
  // SubmitChanges now will NOT create a new transaction/commit each time.
  DoImportStuffThatRunsWithinASingleTransaction();
  // Important: Make sure to COMMIT the transaction.
  // (The transaction used for SubmitChanges is committed to the DB.)
  // This is when the disk sync actually has to happen,
  // but it only happens once, not 3500 times!
  ts.Complete();
}
```

However, the semantics of an approach using a single transaction or a single call to SubmitChanges are different than that of the code above calling SubmitChanges 3500 times and creating 3500 different implicit transactions. In particular, the size of the atomic operations (with respect to the database) is different and may not be suitable for all tasks.

For LINQ2SQL updates, changing the optimistic concurrency model (disabling it or just using a timestamp field, for instance) may result in small performance improvements. The biggest improvement, however, will come from reducing the number of commits that must be performed.

Happy coding.

Comment: Despite it was right in front of my eyes I ignored this on purpose, thinking that in desktop environment this is negligible because of two factors -- SQL CE engine is not reloaded each time, there is no connection penalty. Oh boy, I was soooo far from the truth -- one brace up and instead of almost 5 minutes I got almost 5 seconds (this is a magnitude slower than DirectTable, but is just fine with me). Thank you for cold shower :-).

Answer (score 5):

i'm not positive on this, but it seems like the `db.SubmitChanges()` call should be made outside of the loop.  maybe that would speed things up?